# How to get current GOPATH from code

Tags: go

How do I get the current `GOPATH` from a block of code?

`runtime` only has `GOROOT`:

```
// GOROOT returns the root of the Go tree.
// It uses the GOROOT environment variable, if set,
// or else the root used during the Go build.
func GOROOT() string {
    s := gogetenv("GOROOT")
    if s != "" {
        return s
    }
    return defaultGoroot
}
```

I could make a function that has `GOROOT` replaced with `GOPATH`, but is there a buildin for this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [os.Getenv](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getenv)

From docs:

> Getenv retrieves the value of the environment variable named by the
>   key. It returns the value, which will be empty if the variable is not
>   present.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    )

func main() {
    fmt.Println(os.Getenv("GOPATH"))
}
```

**Update for Go 1.8+**

Go 1.8 has default GOPATH exported via go/build:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/build"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    gopath := os.Getenv("GOPATH")
    if gopath == "" {
        gopath = build.Default.GOPATH
    }
    fmt.Println(gopath)
}
```

Comment: In go 1.8, the GOPATH env var is optional. What if the user doesn't have it? Is there a way to get the default one? I think the go runtime should have a way to get the gopath, letting Go itself figure it out for you.

Comment: @tothemario I posted an answer how you could get the valid `GOPATH` since Go 1.8. However, I agree that ideally the runtime should provide a way of obtaining the user's `GOPATH`.

Comment: @tothemario updated answer using code from Go 1.8's default go path implementation.

Comment: don't forget that GOPATH could have multiple paths listed and separated by the os's path delimiter.

Answer (score 14):

You should use [go/build](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/) package.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/build"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(build.Default.GOPATH)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was messing with this today for something I am working on, and it was more annoying than I'd have expected. In the end, this seemed to work for me in the various tests I did on it (not 'rigorous' tests).

```
goPath := strings.Split(os.Getenv("GOPATH"), string(os.PathListSeparator))
if len(goPath) == 0 {
    goPath = append(goPath, build.Default.GOPATH)
} else if goPath[0] == "" {
    goPath[0] = build.Default.GOPATH
}
```

Note that I decided to use only the 1st path if multiple paths are listed on GOPATH, as I suspect few will have more than 1 path listed, and the first would be where `go get` puts the source (I guess). This code also does not account for if the paths are valid or not.

Also note that to build a file path after getting the GOPATH, I had to use `path/filepath.Join()` not `path.Join()`. The former will use \ on windows if the first arg contains \, and / for others. Although windows can accept / for paths apparently, all of my PATH and GOPATH-like environmental variables are written with the normal \ of windows. `path.Join()` used /, producing an invalid path.

Answer (score 0):

Since Go 1.8, there is a [default `GOPATH`](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH):

> The `GOPATH` environment variable specifies the location of your
>   workspace. It defaults to a directory named go inside your home
>   directory, so `$HOME/go` on Unix, `$home/go` on Plan 9, and
>   `%USERPROFILE%\go` (usually `C:\Users\YourName\go`) on Windows.

This means the `GOPATH` environment variable is not necessarily set to anything in particular.

You can still use `os.Getenv` to get the value, but in case it is not set you need to make sure that you use the the plattform-specific default value instead, for example using [mitchellh/go-homedir](https://github.com/mitchellh/go-homedir):

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "os"

        "github.com/mitchellh/go-homedir"
)

func main() {
        p, err := gopath()
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Error finding GOPATH: %v", err)
        }

        fmt.Println(p)
}

func gopath() (string, error) {
        s := os.Getenv("GOPATH")
        if s != "" {
                return s, nil
        }
        return homedir.Expand("~/go")
}
```

Comment: It's a bit of overkill. We can use code from Go's own source code to get default go path. See https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.8/src/go/build/build.go#L260-L277

Comment: @codefreak There are certainly simpler ways and your answer is valid, too. What I like about `go-homedir` is that when in doubt, it tries multiple ways of finding the home directory, and if all fails, it actually returns an error. So users of this code can return a meaningful error message. If you just return an empty string, users must check if it's empty. Should they neglect that, this might lead to unexpected behavior or weird errors in some edge cases.

Comment: Point of question is to find GOPATH, not home dir. go-homedir is great for finding home dir. But if Go itself uses defaultGOPATH function, what's the point of taking care of edge cases which Go build code itself doesn't take care of. Anyways let's let users decide what they like the most :)