# How to reliably get the projects root in go?

Tags: testing, go

For now I used `runtime.Caller(0)` in combination with `path.Dir` and `filepath.Abs` to get the path to the currently executed file and get the project root relative to it.

So lets say I've a folder structure like this:

```
$GOPATH/src/example.org/myproject
$GOPATH/src/example.org/myproject/main.go
$GOPATH/src/example.org/myproject/path
$GOPATH/src/example.org/myproject/path/loader.go
```

If I want my project root I call the loader.go which in turn gets its path with `runtime.Caller(0)` and then goes up one folder to reach the project root.

The problem is when using `go test -cover` the executed file is not in its normal place anymore but in a special sub directory for the testing and coverage analysis.
`runtime.Caller(0)` gives me the following:

```
example.org/myproject/path/_test/_obj_/loader.go
```

Running it through `path.Dir` and `filepath.Abs` will give me:

```
$GOPATH/src/example.org/myproject/path/example.org/myproject/path/_test/_obj_
```

When I go up from there I won't reach the project root but something totally different obviously. So my questions stands:
Is there any reliable way of getting the project root?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to reference a relative file from code and tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059023/how-to-reference-a-relative-file-from-code-and-tests/31059125#31059125).

Answer (score 3):

You can build it from the `$GOPATH` env variable:

```
gp := os.Getenv("GOPATH")
ap := path.Join(gp, "src/example.org/myproject")
fmt.Println(ap)
```

That will yield the absolute path to your paroject dir:

`/path/to/gopath/src/example.org/myproject`

This obviously only works when `GOPATH` is set. aka. on your dev machine. On production you need to supply directories via a config file.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause problems in production? I don't know where a user might place the binary. So the path needs to be somewhat relative.

Comment: uhm, on production there is only the binary. Your projectroot will not be there anyway, unless you put it there on purpose in which case you know beforehand where it is.

Comment: are you trying to deploy files along with your binary?

Comment: That's correct I want to deploy files alongside my binary. Is this a bad practice?

Comment: Not a bad practice but if that's what you're doing you should offer a config setting to give the path to those files. In production there will be no "project root".

Comment: -1 Sorry. I thought this might work myself, and tried it out before hitting SO. However, if the user doesn't have GOPATH set--instead relying on the platform-dependent default--then the path you construct is incorrect.

Comment: This answer has a reliable way to determine GOPATH. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32650077/262748

Comment: Using GOPATH made it work in dev and production, but broke my tests (both locally and on CI) since the GOPATH seems to be messed up

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537257/how-to-get-the-directory-of-the-currently-running-file#answer-18537419) answer. In case you are using go ~ 1.8, `func Executable() (string, error)` is an option I stumbled over when I needed it. I tested briefly how it interacts with `go test -cover` and it seems to work fine:

> `func Executable() (string, error)`
>
> Executable returns the path name for the executable that started the current process. There is no guarantee that the path is still pointing to the correct executable. If a symlink was used to start the process, depending on the operating system, the result might be the symlink or the path it pointed to. If a stable result is needed, path/filepath.EvalSymlinks might help.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path"
)

func main() {
    e, err := os.Executable()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    path := path.Dir(e)
    fmt.Println(path)
}
```

The test:

`binpath.go`:

```
package binpath

import (
    "os"
    "path"
)

func getBinPath() string {
    e, err := os.Executable()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    path := path.Dir(e)
    return path
}
```

`binpath_test.go`:

```
package binpath

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

func TestGetBinPath(t *testing.T) {
    fmt.Println(getBinPath())
}
```

Results in something like `/tmp/go-build465775039/github.com/tworabbits/binpath/_test`

Comment: If you had a resource in the GOPATH/src/whatever folder, but installed your executable to GOPATH/bin using `go install`, would `os.Executable()` still point to the appropriate directory though?

Comment: This won't work if you run you go script direct ex: `go run main.py`

Answer (score 0):

**Abs** returns an absolute representation of path. If the path is not absolute it will be joined with the current working directory to turn it into an absolute path

```
absPath, err := filepath.Abs()
if err != nil {
    panic("Ooops)
}
```